# Python mysql row deletion problems

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having issues deleting rows from my database with python.  I can hard code it like this:

```
del_student = "DELETE FROM students WHERE sid=34556"
cursor.execute(del_student)
cnx.commit()
```

but I'm trying to get sid from my entry box in my gui and this isn't working:

```
sid=SIDEnt.get()
del_student = "DELETE FROM students WHERE sid=%s"
cursor.execute(del_student,sid)
cnx.commit()
```

I'm rather new to python and I've tried looking through the posted questions already, thanks.

Comment: What is printed if you put `print(repr(sid))` after the `sid=SIDEnt.get()` line ?

Comment: In addition to checking the value of `sid`, I believe that you need to use `?` as a placeholder rather than `%s`.

Comment: If he's using MySQLdb the `%s` is the correct paramstyle.

Answer (score 2):

`sid` needs to be in a tuple.

```
sid=SIDEnt.get()
del_student = "DELETE FROM students WHERE sid=%s"
cursor.execute(del_student,(sid,)) # put `sid` into a one-element tuple
cnx.commit()
```

The [DB-API specifies](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14), "Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping..."

Comment: Here is the [reference to the documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id11) that explains this: _"Why the tuple? Because the DB API requires you to pass in any parameters as a sequence."_

Comment: Thanks for adding that, Burhan. Indeed a one-element list is OK here too.

Comment: Amazing, would have never thought of adding an extra comma after sid, thanks so much.

Comment: @ifonlyirocked and also putting it in a box?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't substituted the '%s' with any values; so your query is this:

```
'DELETE FROM students WHERE sid=%s'
```

it should be as follows:

```
sid=SIDEnt.get()
del_student = "DELETE FROM students WHERE sid=%s"%(sid,)
cursor.execute(del_student,sid)
cnx.commit()
```

Comment: You definitely do NOT want to use "%" in SQL, as it may allow an ''SQL injection''. Even if the variable 'sid' cannot be accessed by an attacker in this particular case, it is considered bad practice to use it.